# How i can change attr to value from choisen option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this -

```
<a id="size" href="#" data-name="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" data-article="<?php the_field('article'); ?>" data-size="" data-price="<?php the_field('price'); ?>" class="add-to-cart btn">
<button>Add Item</button>
</a>
```

And this -

```
<?php
 $values = get_field('size');
  if($values) {
     echo '<select>';
         foreach($values as $value) {
      echo '<option>' . $value . '</option>'; }
echo '</select>'; 
  }
?>
```

If i choise some option from my select i needed then `data-size=""` change on `data-size="_valuefromchoisedoption_"`

This is my js how i add item in shopping card -

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
    var article = $(this).data('article');
    var size = Number($(this).data('size'));
    shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, article, size, 1);
    displayCart();

    $(function(){
       I need help to add srctipt on this place.
    })
```

I change the option and click to the add button and data-size changing on value of choisen option.

Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that on change of select option, data-size attribute of anchor tag should update with the value from selected option.

1) Attach a function to select element as onchange attribute which will be called when select option changes.

2) Get selected text value of option:

```
$(ele).children("option:selected").text()
```

3) Update anchor tag attribute:

```
$('#size').attr('data-size', $(ele).children("option:selected").text())
```

Check below code snippet:

```js
function populateField(ele) {
  $('#size').attr('data-size', $(ele).children("option:selected").text())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="size" data-size="">test</a>

<select onchange="populateField(this);">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thx for feedback. If i add this code to my oath - it dosnt work. But i add your code to the my .php page between html tag and this is work!

Comment: Is your my oath code same as snippet which is attached in question?